# Good Tutorial on Cassandra and also a small database inquery

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I have a two part question.

1) Are there any good tutorials explaining how Cassandra's system works with column families, super column families and all of that jazz?  I was reading through the documentation but was left a bit confused....
2) I am also designing my MYSQL tables at the moment and have full intention to switch them to Cassandra in a few months when I finish all of the new features and have the time to start transferring the data.  I have a schema at the moment which is something similar to the following:

```
Folders:
  folder_id
  folder_name
  ...

Files:
  file_id
  file_name
  ...
```

And now I have two possible solutions since Cassandra does not support joins, i could treat it as i normally would with a normalized system and do this:

```
Folders:
  folder_id
  folder_name
  ...

Folder_files:
  folder_id
  file_id

Files:
  file_id
  file_name
  ...
```

or I could create duplicates and eliminate one of the queries from 3 queries to 2 queries:

```
Folders:
  folder_id
  file_id
  folder_name
  ...

Files:
  file_id
  file_name
  ...
```

Which one would be recommended?  Thanks for any tutorials and info on this simple database setup :)

Comment: Think on how will you be querying for folders and files? By id? By name? Do I want to get all files of a folder? Then arrange you data according.

Comment: I will be querying by folder ids, and generally I will be getting all files for a folder, i can't see many situations when I wouldn't be.  I am not really sure how to arrange the data, as I am coming from a RMDBS mindset and I need to be given a new way of thinking in order to do this properly, i am starting to grasp some of the concepts but I am not solidified yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be querying by folder ids to get all files for a folder then this seems appropriate:

```
Folder_Files: 
  folder_id 
  file_id 
  file_name 
  ...
```

Comment: So I should use 2 tables/column families instead of 3, correct?  This would mean I will have duplicate data, but from what I have read this seems to be a standard thing.

Comment: Right, denormalize your database and make "select" statements very fast.